# How do I add an offset to GLM model in R?

Tags: r, offset, glm

I am solving Agresti's exercise 4.10 of Categorical Data Analysis.

He provides the table

```
     Aortic | Mitral

<55       4       1
       1259    2082

55+       7       9
       1417    1647
```

The rows represent age group, the columns the type of heart valve and the two numbers in each cell are number of deaths (top) and total time length (bottom). He then suggests the model
$$
\log(\mu_{ij}) = \alpha + 1 \times \log(t_{ij}) + \beta_1 a_i + \beta_2 \nu_j
$$
in which $t_{ij}$ is  the total time length of cell $(i,j),$ $a_i$ is the indicator variable of "55+" and $\nu_j$ the indicator of "Mitral."

Exercise 4.10 then asks to find a 95% profile likelihood confidence interval for $\beta_1.$ I understand what this means mathematically, but I have trouble with the actual coding in `R`. I am using the `R` library "ProfileLikelihood."

This is my attempt:

```
heart_table <- data.frame(
  y = c(9,7,1,4),
  tot_time = c(1647,1417,2082,1259),
  age = c(1,1,0,0), #1 means 55+
  valve = c(1,0,1,0) #1 means mitral
)
heart_prof <- profilelike.glm(
  y ~ valve,
  data = heart_table,
  family = poisson(),
  offset.glm = log(tot_time),
  profile.theta = "age",
  lo.theta = -.5,
  hi.theta = 3.5
)
```

It produces an error

```
Error: object 'tot_time' not found
```

If I quote `log(tot_time)` I get a different error, that is,

```
heart_prof <- profilelike.glm(
  y ~ valve,
  data = heart_table,
  family = poisson(),
  offset.glm = "log(tot_time)",
  profile.theta = "age",
  lo.theta = -.5,
  hi.theta = 3.5
)
```

produces

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ -1 + X + offset(pi * theta.off) +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'offset(glm.off)'
```

I have also tried using the formulas

```
y ~ valve + offset.glm(log(tot_time))
```

with error

```
Error in offset.glm(log(tot_time)) : could not find function "offset.glm"
```

And the formula

```
y ~ valve + offset(log(tot_time))
```

which produces no error (it runs). However, this feels wrong since the documentation of profilelike.glm it is stated that "offset   should not be provided. Instead use offset.glm."

ProfileLikelihood documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ProfileLikelihood/ProfileLikelihood.pdf

Comment: I don't know package ProfileLikelihood, but try `offset.glm = log(heart_table$tot_time)` in your first code, maybe it helps.

Comment: Produces the error: "Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ -1 + X + offset(pi * theta.off) +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'offset(glm.off)'"

Comment: Sounds cryptic - you could try to ask on stackoverflow. You could also look what happens if you save log(tot_time) in a vector and use that vector as offset.glm.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error 
messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic 
here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have, or know, that package, but you don't need it.  You can fit a Poisson regression model in base R, and you can get confidence intervals based on profiling the likelihood by calling `confint`.  Consider:

```
> heart_table <- data.frame(
+   y = c(9,7,1,4),
+   tot_time = c(1647,1417,2082,1259),
+   age = c(1,1,0,0), #1 means 55+
+   valve = c(1,0,1,0) #1 means mitral
+ )
> m = glm(y~valve+offset(log(tot_time)), data=heart_table, family="poisson")
> summary(m)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ valve + offset(log(tot_time)), family = "poisson", 
    data = heart_table)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4  
 1.9095   0.4718  -2.3931  -0.5383  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -5.4942     0.3015 -18.222   <2e-16 ***
valve        -0.4271     0.4369  -0.978    0.328    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 10.8405  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  9.8857  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 27.013

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> confint(m)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -6.149598 -4.9562364
valve       -1.302631  0.4365193
```